# Method 'SaveAs' of Object '_Workbook' failed, but only on one computer

Tags: excel, vba, methods

I have a program that was working. I added support for another data file. On one of my coworkers computers the code throws an error referring to the save as method being the cause.

A thread I found suggests that a date format could be the issue, but that doesn't make sense at this point in the save procedure.

It saves the file with the correct name, even asks me if I want to replace a file with the same name, then after the save file is created the debugger throws the error.

It didn't happen the first time I ran the program on this machine. It threw an error further down in the code and when I reran with breakpoints it started throwing the error in the save function.

Another thread mentioned that Active workbook may be causing problems and using ThisWorkbook might work better.

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` is the line throwing the error, and after it makes the file.

```vb
Private Sub SaveAsNew(parseName As String, path As String)
Dim sheetToCopy As String
sheetToCopy = "Sheet1"
Worksheets(sheetToCopy).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs path & "\" & parseName & "StandardForm.xlsx"
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing the macro. If the code fails only on one computer, have you looked to see what's different about that machine? Does the user have write access to the directory you want to save the file to? Does it even exist on that machine?

Comment: They are able to save and delete files, so I assume they have write access. Not sure about what permissions or if they are on a restricted account. They run windows 10 while I am on 11, I'm not sure if that would have an effect on excel working.  It seems as though the SaveAs function is what is throwing the fit, but I why when it was working?

Comment: `Activeworkbook` may come into play if they have a personal.xlsb for example and, for some reason, something triggered its code (An UDF to name something). As stated, refer whenever you can to `ThisWorkbook` or  better yet `Set WB= ""`.

Answer (score 0):

### Export Worksheet to New Workbook

- If an error occurs, there will be a message in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub SaveAsNew(ByVal ParseName As String, ByVal DestPath As String)
    Const ProcName As String = "SaveAsNew"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' enable error-trapping
    
    ' Source - copy a worksheet
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' Destination - save a single-worksheet workbook
    Const dRightName As String = "StandardForm.xlsx"
    
    ' Determine the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = DestPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    
    ' Validate the existence of the destination folder path.
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & dFolderPath & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error-trapping
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' re-enable error-trapping
    
    ' Validate the existence of the source worksheet.
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet '" & sName & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Return a copy of the source worksheet in a new single-worksheet workbook.
    sws.Copy
    
    ' Reference this workbook, the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    ' Write the destination file path to a variable
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & ParseName & dRightName
    
    ' Save the destination workbook (file).
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' If you don't overwrite, when you press 'No' or 'Cancel',
    ' an error will occur.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it's already saved
    
    ' Validate the success.
    Success = True

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error-trapping (to avoid an endless loop)
        If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ' Inform.
        If Success Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet exported.", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbCritical
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error-trapping
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```