# sort program breaking after second file attempt

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a VBA/excel program that scans an excel file or a pdf file to extract relevant data and save to a seperate sorted sheet.

The vba/excel program runs fine on my machine but on my coworkers computers it only runs one of the files and then throws an error when trying to run a second file unless the vba/excel program is closed and then reopened.

I thought this could have something to do with the connections related to the queries not being cleared, but after attempting to add code to clear the connections as well my code resorted back to the original problem I  was having... [VBA Method 'SaveAs' of Object '_Workbook' faild, but only on one computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718713/vba-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-faild-but-only-on-one-computer?noredirect=1#comment128446673_72718713)

What is going on here? Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Run-time Error '1004': Document not saved.

Comment: and there is no suggestion to any code being at fault

Comment: How are `path` and `parsename` populated?

Comment: path is calculated from a dialog box with this code wrapped in a function: Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)   .   .   . Then parseName is the first 16letters of the selected data file's name (basically it cuts off the file extension).  .  .  And all of this works fine on my machine

Comment: I don't have any suggestions other than checking all the previous posts here on this same error and ruling out the various issues other folks had: https://www.google.com/search?q=1004+%22Document+not+saved%22+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: What versions of excel are you using? I would suggest to check if you use both same..